# Reading inner data from json in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have below JSON in my angular application

```
var alphas = {
"Data":
{
    "1" : {
            "abc": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    },
            "abc2": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    }   
          },
          
    "2" : {
        "11" :{
            "abc": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    },
            "abc2": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    }
                }
          },
    "3" : {
            "abc": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    },
            "abc2": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    }   
          }
}
```

}

I can read inner data like alphas["Data"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=49&ssc=28&pln=49&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBHSOMTQAgOYQAXlAAG9FABIABEABE6gw2YUWcyWeyAIxs0D5JmswXshjSWC8iVSqVs%20KQPAi-JsgBqDGg7EgIt4ksVytVACZeVqdXrzYbFYKAL62pUy2Dm8UCu0mtUW7W6-Vsp3GlV4N2Wv02o1S%200so0lR2x0CStnmsUKwVsoUisUe9Mu%20U5pXB9VhvUGyPp4Oh33WgPllnx40ut1poOq4vV-2Bwtmn1WyARu318v2hMN9kAZlF7sjbLz08HXvbfbLC8rvfDtcHY9zsubBYrbfXpc3nrXGo7A7t0dHrJHI8UCE4giOqGxDIzooYwmflE4IwA3MEj6CPA7gBNA8DMAAFDqNJfgA2py3JsgAuvBppoT%20YjCMGRKoO0RKwbSiFcqgPJoRhKEAJSAcEKg4M0HhkF4iDwH0MocDQXxuGYzDsAwzCQPwsDQOoiQcXoIheGyACiqwMIgCz6KKbGgGy4AOKgADkwgAHKQBIbJBCoADyXxkO8ghCVokAvo4CiuNIeCgE4rE6MMWD6CgCCINCwiXNxEhsdEIgGBw2ILEwrAcDwQQlEAA) to get all inner data & reading alphas["Data"][2] also give inner data. So it will give result like below

```
"11" :{
            "abc": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    },
            "abc2": {
                    "key1":"Value1",
                    "key2":"Value2",
                    }
                }
          }
```

Here we can see that it will also return that number "11" & all other inner data is returned.
Is there any way to get only "11" as data or extracting it from inner data in separate variable ?
I was trying to read data like below

```
const str = "1" as string ;
alphas["Data"][2][str as keyof typeof alphas["Data"][2]]
```

But it is returning undefined result.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=49&ssc=28&pln=49&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBHSOMTQAgOYQAXlAAG9FABIABEABE6gw2YUWcyWeyAIxs0D5JmswXshjSWC8iVSqVs%20KQPAi-JsgBqDGg7EgIt4ksVytVACZeVqdXrzYbFYKAL62pUy2Dm8UCu0mtUW7W6-Vsp3GlV4N2Wv02o1S%200so0lR2x0CStnmsUKwVsoUisUe9Mu%20U5pXB9VhvUGyPp4Oh33WgPllnx40ut1poOq4vV-2Bwtmn1WyARu318v2hMN9kAZlF7sjbLz08HXvbfbLC8rvfDtcHY9zsubBYrbfXpc3nrXGo7A7t0dHrJHI8UCE4giOqGxDIzooYwmflE4IwA3MEj6CPA7gBNA8DMAAFDqNJfgA2py3JsgAuvBppoT%20YjCMGRKoO0RKwbSiFcqgPJoRhKEAJSAcEKg4M0HhkF4iDwH0MocDQXxuGYzDsAwzCQPwsDQOoiQcXoIheGyACiqwMIgCz6KKbGgGy4AOKgADkwgAHKQBIbJBCoADyXxkO8ghCVokAvo4CiuNIeCgE4rE6MMWD6CgCCINCwiXNxEhsdEIgGBw2ILEwrAcDwQQlEAA)

Comment: The "_number 11_" is a property of that object. Perhaps you are looking for `alphas["Data"][2][11]`? That will return `{ "abc": ... }`

Comment: @JDB Well that number 11 can be any number, so can not do it directly like that. I want to find out that number first & after that I can do like you are saying

Comment: How about `console.log(Object.keys(alphas["Data"][2]));`

Comment: Thank @AdityaParab I was able to get "11" value

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(Object.values(alphas.Data)[1])[0]
```

Well, it's a joke. You have a json that are object of object of object of ... so you can use
[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
or
[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

to "ride over" the object